# Django-recurrence Parsing

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have a recurrence in the database from Django-recurrence - http://django-recurrence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html 
Note: This utility provide a Jscript UI interface to dateutil.rrule - It is used for working with recurring dates in Django.

```
'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;UNTIL=20170511T050000Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU\n'
 'RDATE:20170224T060000Z\n'
 'EXDATE:20170228T060000Z',
```

How do I parse this?

Comment: parse it for what reason? the occurance field should contain all the information you need already parsed. please clarify a little your use case

Comment: I want to extract frequecy, Byday, edate,  exdate..... and use it for some scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

As per given Documentation of django-recurrence, you can use ***occurrences()***  to generate range of dates.
 Here is general syntax:

```
date_obj = Project.objects.get(id=1).start_date_recurrence_field.occurrences()

for i in date_obj:
    print(i)
```

Here you will get list of your dates printed.
Let me know if you still didn't get that.